# Decoding JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, decoding

REST_API provides a JSON Object like this:

```
[
   {
      "key1":"value1"
      "key2":"value2"
   }
]
```

Question:
How can I Parse that with Dart? I do not get it running.
My main problem is that any approach with json.decode will remove all annotations so strings are no longer strings.

Sure I could cut of the square brackets at the beginning and at the end but thats not what i would call good coding.

Maybe some of you can help ;-)

Have a great day!

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68927261/2804581

Comment: Yes that was the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var _response = JsonDecode(response.body) ; 
print(_response[0]['key1']);
```